# need help in sed command to search and replace a string pattern

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I am new to sed and i am trying on some sed expressions:

i have multiple file having line with pattern:

```
ABC * 123
ABC * 245
ABC * 456
```

it means a string being multiplied by some integer.

i need to replace all integers values with a constant integer

```
ABC * 25
ABC * 25
ABC * 25
```

i tried with:

```
sed 's/\(ABC\s+\*\s+\)[0-9]+/1 25/g' myfile.txt
```

but its doing nothing and returning same file as output.

Files have other text too. Also lines also have some other text as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sed` dialect probably doesn't understand `\s` for whitespace, and/or `+` for one or more repetitions.  Also you forgot the backslash for the backref.

```
sed 's/\(ABC \+\* \+\)[0-9]\+/\125/g' myfile.txt
```

This doesn't cope with tabs, and you might have to fiddle with `\+` if it doesn't accept that either.

The most portable solution is probably to use Perl instead.

```
perl -pe 's/(ABC\s+\*\s+)\d+/$125/' myfile.txt
```

Comment: You get an extra space before the `25`, to fix use: `sed 's/\(ABC \+\* \+\)[0-9]\+/\125/g'` Also same with `perl`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`

```
awk '/ABC/ {$3="25"}1' myfile.txt
ABC * 25
ABC * 25
ABC * 25
```

Here is an update that change the digit after ABC anywhere in the line

```
cat file
ABC * 123
sometext ABC * 245
some more ABC * 456 not my text
```

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="ABC") $(i+2)="25"}1' file
ABC * 25
sometext ABC * 25
some more ABC * 25 not my text
```

A `gnu awk` version

```
awk '{print gensub(/(ABC \* )[0-9]+/,"\\125","g")}' file
ABC * 25
sometext ABC * 25
some more ABC * 25 not my text
```

Comment: Thanks Jotne but my line can have other text asw ell in starting and end like sometext ABC * 234 sometext

Comment: Updated with a version working if ABC is inn between other text.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/[[:alpnum]][[:space:]]*// s/\([[:space:]]\{1,\}\)[[:digit:]]\{1,}$/\125/' myfile.txt
```

if all line are multiple like your sample

```
sed 's/\([[:space:]]\{1,\}\)[[:digit:]]\{1,}$/\125/' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If your numeric part is always at the end of the line, you can do this:

```
sed -e "s/[0-9]*$/25/"
```

which says "replace multiple digits at the end of the line with 25"

Or if the digits are always surrounded by spaces:

```
sed -e "s/\s[0-9]*\s/25/"
```

Comment: It may not bee, see OPs comment on my post.

Comment: Thanks you, Jotne. I guess we can go on guessing all the permutations of what the OP might have forever;-)   I guess he could use this then      sed -e "s/\s[0-9]*\s/25/"